# Highcharts - Hide export menu in print page

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts. I want to print charts. Now the problem is I am getting the export button in the print page also which I do not want. How do I disable/hide that button in print page?

Try this fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/6hyfk/34/

Here's highchart code

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{  
        data: [1, 2, 3]        
    }]
});

$("#b").click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.setSize(200,500, false);
    chart.print();
    setTimeout(function() {
        chart.setSize(600,500, false);
    }, 1000);

});
});
```

[image: Hide/disable export button in print page]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the [beforePrint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.beforePrint) / [afterPrint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.afterPrint) events and then manipulate on SVG elements.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    beforePrint:function() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.hide();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].hide();
    },
    afterPrint:function() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.show();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].show();
    }
  }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8cxe2ww/

Comment: Just what I want. Thanks.